# How to customize the appearance of newicktree

Tags: pstricks, newicktree

I'm currently preparing a seminar for some students. One student asked me the question whether it's possible to draw phylogenetic trees with LaTeX or not. Some research brought the [`newicktree`](http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/)-package to my eye.

The following MWE is available on the [website](http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/) of the developer and is used to check, if everything is working.

Is there any way to customize single nodes to be in different colors? And is there a way to print the number for the branches with a comma as a decimal marker?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newicktree}

\begin{document}

\begin{newicktree}
\drawtree{((\bf My:1,first:1.5):0.5,(\sf newicktree:2,tree!:2.5):0.5):0.5;}
\end{newicktree}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a different color use:

```
\begin{newicktree}
\nodelabelformat {\color{red}}%% for all
\drawtree{((\bf\color{blue} My:1,first:1.5):0.5,(\sf newicktree:2,tree!:2.5):0.5):0.5;}%% for a single
\end{newicktree}
```

To get a comma instead of the dot you have to redefine the macro. Not easy, but possible.

Comment: Now the text is in different color, that's one approach, yes. Is it possible to mark a single dot, a node, in color? Like [this one here](http://i.imgur.com/yHU89E4.png).

Comment: P.S.: Forgot to mention, that I edited the color of the node with GIMP.

Comment: Yes, but needs also a redefinition of existing macros, as far as I know.

Comment: I'll have a look into the code tomorrow

Comment: That's really generous. Thanks a lot `:)`

Comment: It is too much work to modify the macros. The authors should have used optional arguments for the several branches. But they didn't. However, if you need relative simple trees it is much easier to so it with lines or nodes, then you can change everything.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much indeed for your help. I haven't worked with pstricks yet, so I haven't any idea how to start to modify the code of the package. I'll accept the answer -- thanks again for the help `:)`